# Webview javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

I am opening a url in my webview. It has a js function in body onload. Ideally it should get executed. And it does on chrome browser. But on webview it doesnt. I checked the console and this error was there

```
synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated
```

Can anyone of you help in this regard?? Since this page is working on desktop the owner of page is not doing changes. So what can be done at webview level to get around this issue??

Comment: do you really need to send xhr synchronously? if not just use asynchronous xhr

Comment: @mylee it is not a webpage that I own. Basically it is payment gateways page and I have no control over it.

Comment: that's not an error in the console, it's just a warning; the code should not stop working because that message appears. something else is wrong. sprinkle some logs along the path and figure out where the webview gets lost.

Comment: @dandavis Where exactly can i put logs if u have ny idea?? I can only call the onConsole method to my knowledge

Comment: can you use alert()? or, send them to a server with ajax. or just write them to the screen

Comment: I can use alert() but what exactly should I alert()? @dandavis

Comment: it's more about where than what, so alert(1) should work to make sure the code is firing. i would alert before and after the sjax to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making synchronous XHR? Do you really need to do that? Keep in mind that with sync. request, until the browser receives the response from the server, the UI will stay frozen making it completely useless. Its almost never a good practice to do sync. XHR.

Comment: Hey Prashant, I do not have control over the webpage. Basically it is a payment gateway(RUPAY) page. I am just using it in my app whenever transaction happens